# What is the pause called at the apex of an object's trajectory?

Tags: soft-question, newtonian-gravity, terminology, orbital-motion

My apologies for such a basic question--I am a musician, not a physicist. But I cannot anywhere find the word, if one exists, that describes that elegant pause of an object such as a ball, thrown straight up, as it reaches the apex of its trajectory's power and before it obeys the power of gravity commanding it to earth.

Comment: In musician's terms, isn't it anacrusis?

Comment: In rock-climber terms, it's a "deadpoint" :-)

Comment: I know you were writing poetically, but to be a bit pedantic: This pause lasts zero seconds, the instantaneous velocity of the ball is zero only at a point in time. The ball is obeying the power of gravity as it ascends - because it's velocity is continuously reducing in accordance with v=u+at.

Comment: There is no pause.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a word apart from "apex" or its various synonyms. For orbiting bodies we use the prefix "ap" e.g. [aphelion](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphelion) is the point an object orbiting the sun is furthest away, or [apastron](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apastron) is the equivalent for a star. A object thrown up is in principle orbiting the Earth (OK, it's a **highly** elliptical orbit :-) so I suppose the apex of its flight would be the [apogee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apogee).

Comment: I note that even though they both start with *ap*, the word *apogee* is from a Greek root while *apex* is Latin. I suppose the Latin word might also originally have come from a Greek root.

Comment: @PM2Ring no, the trajectory of a thrown object is elliptical. It is approximately parabolic if we make the approximation that $g$ is constant. (Ignoring air resistance of course)

Comment: Fair enough. And of course the air resistance is far more significant than the variation in $g$ for any object propelled by human muscle power.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the word you're looking for is Apogee.